# Using VBA to select non-adjacent range

Tags: string, vba, excel, syntax

I know how to select a range till a calculated last row using vba as such:

```
Range("P3:R" & LastRow).Select
```

Is there a way to select non-adjacent column data? For example I want cells from column N to R **WITHOUT** column O

Tried below, but it ends up selecting O too, I suspect because the `"` character should encompass the whole thing, but then how do I keep the variable value for last row?

```
Range("N3:N" & LastRow , "P3:R" & LastRow).Select
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

You could use the [Union](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/application-union-method-excel) method, not that you usually need to Select anything...

```
Union(Range("N3:N" & LastRow), Range("P3:R" & LastRow)).Select
```

Answer (score 8):

you can use

```
Range("N3:N" & LastRow & "," & "P3:R" & LastRow).Select
```

or

```
Intersect(Range("N:N, P:R"), Rows(3).Resize(LastRow - 3)).Select
```

Comment: Good spot, I hadn't noticed the misplaced comma. You could do `Range("N3:N" & LastRow & ",P3:R" & LastRow).Select`

Comment: @SJR, True. But I left that comma alone just to "mark" its proper place