# VBA Highlight cells that contain a space

Tags: excel, vba

After my formulas and macros run, Im looking to highlight the cells in my worksheet that are outputted as a `""`  (Result of an If Formula).

It is a dynamic range, and I am having difficulty finding a way to change the color of *Just* the cells with a space.  Any ideas would be very helpful.

```
Dim cell As Variant
For Each cell In Sheets("[Sheet name here]").UsedRange.Columns("U").Cells
    If InStr(cell.Value, "") = 0 Then
    cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 15
    End If
Next cell
End Sub
```

Then I basically repeated it for column "D", but it takes an unusually long time to complete...

Im thinking i can implement the
`=LEN(??)=0` function, but not sure how to do so...

Comment: `""` is not a space but an empty string.

Comment: Hi Aaron & welcome to the forum. Please post your code and also what you have tried so far. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: @ScottCraner the formula is as follows: =IFNA(IF(VLOOKUP(B14,partscrt,1,FALSE)=B14,""),"X") Can you think of a better way to Either display a blank, or an X ?

Comment: I was just stating that your statement of it being a `Space` is incorrect as it is an empty string.  A space would be `" "` not `""`.

Comment: As to the code `If cell.Value = "" Then`

Comment: does this need to be VBA? You could accomplish this with conditional formatting.

Comment: @tigeravatar no, it does not need to be VBA.  whenever I Tried conditional formatting, it colored EVERYTHING that was blank, where i only want the used range...

Comment: Since you are looking for a space character, the use "If InStr(cell.Value, CHR(32)) = 0 Then".  CHR(32) uses the the ASCII number for a space

Answer (score 0):

The reason it is running so slow is that you're calling Excel Object for every cell in your range. If column U has 1,000 cells that aren't empty then that is 1,000 calls to the Excel object model.

It is much faster to read the entire range into memory at one time and then process it in memory. This is very easy to do. The code below reads cells A1:A100 but the key difference is that it only calls the Excel Object one time (instead of 100 times).

```
Dim MyData As Variant
MyData = Range("A1:A100").Value
```

For your code you would do something like this ...

```
  Dim MyData As Variant
  Dim i As Long

  MyData = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns("U").Cells.Value
  For i = 1 To UBound(MyData)
    If (MyData(i, 1) = "") Then
      'keep track of which cells need to be colored
    End If
  Next
```

If you have a lot of cells that need coloring, you will need to use a "non-contiguous" range selecting in order to perform this with one call to Excel's object model. See this article for more information [Using VBA to select non-adjacent range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49780635/using-vba-to-select-non-adjacent-range)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all.  In this instance, I ended up modifying my formulas to actually generate a space " " instead of a null string, "" as @Scott Craner pointed out.

With a legitimate space, I just achieved the same results using conditional formatting, as @tigeravatar suggested.

Thank you all for the help, I really appreciate it !